# Build a query in Oracle 11g with rownum in output

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I have a scenario and build a Oracle query for it.

Table Columns: Plan_No, Invoice_No,Order_Dt. One plan will have more than one invoice.

I want get this output:

```
Plan_No Invoice_No   Order_Dt   Row_No
A1       1001        23-May-17  1
A1       1002        10-Apr-17  2
A1       1003        12-Jan-17  3
A1       1004      11-Nov-16    4
B1       1001      10-May-17    1
B1      2008       10-Feb-17    2
B1      3308       12-Dec-16    3
C1      5007       23-May-17    1
C1      5585       10-Apr-17    2
C1     52545       12-Jan-17    3
C1      5228       11-Nov-16    4
C1      21488       2-Jan-16    5
C1      51546      16-Apr-15    6
```

Comment: I was trying to use row_num but it did not work

Comment: Please show us your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY plan_no ORDER BY Invoice_No) AS row_nbr,
    * 
FROM 
    table
```